# Why do WordPress installations retrieve the crypto secrets remotely on installation?

Tags: encryption, tls, php

It seems that WordPress [retrieves all the crypto constants remotely](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fd838ccb2b1d37bda02eecdf09c324863f050812/wp-admin/setup-config.php#L211) (via HTTPS):

```
// setup-config.php
$secret_keys = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/' );
```

- Are there any benefits to doing this instead of generating the keys locally?
- Is this completely unnecessary? Will it only provide another attack vector to WordPress setups?

Comment: Great material for a conspiracy theory. :)

Comment: I opened [#35290](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35290) to address this design flaw and promote more-secure-by-default practices.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is arguably bad design, but one can understand where the design came from.

It is arguably bad design, because it relies upon `api.wordpress.org` to generate random keys and keep them secret.  If `api.wordpress.org` gets compromised, then the attackers could arrange to record the keys that are used by new Wordpress installations.  That would be problematic.

(Yes, Wordpress could send you backdoored source code, but that would be detectable in principle by anyone who examines the source code -- as you have done.  In contrast, if `api.wordpress.org` is secretly recording a copy of the keys it sends to new Wordpress installations, that is not detectable by any amount of source code inspection or any other mechanism available to interested third parties.)

It is understandable, because it is hard to generate crypto-quality randomness in a platform-independent way.

It's still arguably a bit sloppy/lazy.  Arguably, a better design would have been to gather some local randomness (if possible), gather some randomness from `api.wordpress.org`, and then mix the two securely using a cryptographic hash function.  That way, you'll be secure as long as either of those two values is good.  A compromise of `api.wordpress.org` would not endanger Wordpress installations running on any platform where the code was able to gather some local randomness; it would only endanger the small minority of installations that were unable to get good randomness.

How can one generate good crypto-quality randomness, from local sources?  There are various ways:

- Read 16 bytes from `/dev/urandom`, if it exists.
- Call `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, which [invokes OpenSSL to get crypto-quality pseudorandom bits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).
- Call `mcrypt_create_iv()`, with the `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` flag.
- Of course, one can try all available options and mix together everything you get.  As long as at least one of these options work, you'll be good.  And of course, if you mix this together with output from `api.wordpress.org` using a cryptographic function, it'll never be any worse than today's approach, and will be better if `api.wordpress.org` ever gets compromised.

So, combining local and remote randomness would have been a better approach.  Unfortunately, that does require a bit more work and a bit more code.  Perhaps the developers took the easier approach of just querying `api.wordpress.org`.  One could debate that design decision, but you can understand how this approach might have been chosen.

Overall, though, as Thomas Pornin argues, this is probably not the biggest security risk with Wordpress.  We're talking about software with a long history of security vulnerabilities.  So, the incremental risk added by this aspect of their random-number generation might be small, compared to the risk you're already taking either way.

See also [*Secure random number generation in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1182584/781723) for more on generating crypto-quality random numbers from PHP, and [*Would it be secure to use random numbers from random.org in a cryptographic solution?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1619/351) for more on why it is not a great idea to rely upon a remote source of random numbers for your crypto keys.

Comment: Follow-up: PHP 7 offers `random_bytes()` and I helped write a polyfill for PHP 5.x which landed in WordPress 4.4.

Answer (score 16):

Same reason its [very difficult](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/02/random-seeds-in-ubuntu-1404-lts-cloud.html) to generate your own entropy, particularly in a cloud or shared hosting environment.

Essentially, WordPress is saying that they have more entropy than you do. They are probably right! So they generate it and return it.

It is a possible attack vector. However, I don't think its likely, because if it's targeted, the attacker needs to be in control of your network already to redirect the DNS call to the proper server. THEN, they need to fake a SSL certificate. All told, highly unlikely.

Comment: An attacker could hack the server providing entropy to provide "less random" output, which would be close to undetectable, but would weaken security for all new installations. I am fairly sure one could come up with an all-caps name for such an endeavor.

Comment: Right.  If `api.wordpress.org` is hacked, the hackers don't even need to provide less-random output; they could just record a copy of all the random numbers provided to anyone, leaving new installations screwed.  It would be basically impossible for anyone other than Wordpress admins to detect such an attack.

Comment: It seems like WordPress should mix entropy from api.wordpress.com and a local source.  Then an attack on api.wordpress.org could only compromise servers which had low entropy, rather than all servers.

Answer (score 13):

The URL is: `https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`

Thus, it uses SSL. Even if attackers subvert the DNS to redirect that call, they would still have to somehow own a valid server certificate containing the `api.wordpress.org` name. As such, it is probably difficult for attackers to run a fake key generating server.

Of course, the WordPress server itself would be able to record all keys that it generated, and betray you. Note, though, that they can *already* do that by inserting backdoors in their software -- that you use (they may even call backdoors "vulnerabilities" and plausibly claim that they did not do it on purpose). In that sense, you are already trusting the WordPress people; with this server-side key generation thing, you just keep on trusting them. Personally I would not worry too much about it (at least, not as much as the mere fact of using a PHP-based framework with a long history of questionable security).

As @jrg points out, generating keys securely can be challenging in some cloud-based environments: a computer gets randomness by measuring physical events from the hardware; in a virtual machine there is no actual hardware to measure. Specifically, some cloud providers instantiate machines by using VM snapshots. All machines issuing from a common snapshot thus share the same initial state, in particular any random seed. Using server-side key generation avoids that issue.

Comment: I don't fully buy the comparison to backdoors in the source code.  There is an important difference: if the source code is backdoored, there is at least the potential for detecting the backdoor by inspecting the source code; whereas if `api.wordpress.org` is hacked and the attackers record a copy of all random numbers it ever provides, there is no way (even in principle) for third parties to detect that.  So I don't think this risk is 100% equivalent to that of backdoors in the source code.  I do agree with your bottom line that, in the end, this isn't the biggest worry about Wordpress.

Comment: Well, maybe this **is** one of those "plausibly deniable" backdoors!